# How to give rownumber as a column when you create a view in mysql DB?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a select query, which can auto generate the rownumber column as ID in result.

```
SELECT
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS rowID,
    `tt`.`STATUS` AS `STATUS`,
    `tt`.`PERFORMED_BY` AS `PERFORMED_BY`,
    `tt`.`TMS_LOAD_ID` AS `TMS_LOAD_ID`,
    `tt`.`SHIP_LOCATION_ID` AS `SHIP_LOCATION_ID`,
    `tt`.`TRIP_END_TIME` AS `TRIP_END_TIME`,
    `tt`.`COMMENTS` AS `ASSIGN_DETAILS_COMMENT`,
   
FROM
    abc as tt
                       
    JOIN(
    SELECT
        @curRow := 0
    ) r
```

But when I create the view, it tells me the select commmand has paratemers.

How can I fix this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you are using MySQL version 8+, you can just use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) AS rowID,
    STATUS AS STATUS,
    PERFORMED_BY AS PERFORMED_BY,
    TMS_LOAD_ID AS TMS_LOAD_ID,
    SHIP_LOCATION_ID AS SHIP_LOCATION_ID,
    TRIP_END_TIME AS TRIP_END_TIME,
    COMMENTS AS ASSIGN_DETAILS_COMMENT
FROM abc;
```

Note carefully that the call to `ROW_NUMBER` features an `ORDER BY` clause, which determines which row will be numbered 1, 2, etc.  Without `ORDER BY`, neither the above call to `ROW_NUMBER` nor your user variable approach even makes much sense.

That being said, if you are stuck with MySQL 5.7 or earlier, you *might* be able to use a correlated subquery to simulate the row number:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc t2 WHERE t2.some_col < t1.some_col) AS rowID,
    STATUS AS STATUS,
    PERFORMED_BY AS PERFORMED_BY,
    TMS_LOAD_ID AS TMS_LOAD_ID,
    SHIP_LOCATION_ID AS SHIP_LOCATION_ID,
    TRIP_END_TIME AS TRIP_END_TIME,
    COMMENTS AS ASSIGN_DETAILS_COMMENT
FROM abc t1
```

This approach would work well if `some_col` never had duplicate values.